# How to predict trajectory of a stochastic process under a nonlinear mapping?

Tags: measurement-error, nonlinear

I have a nonlinear model $$N_{t+1} = r  N_t  \exp (-N_t)$$ with some simulated values $$N^*_{t+1} = r  N_t  \exp (-N_t+ \varepsilon_{t+1}) $$

$N^*_t$ (having independent errors $\varepsilon_t$ following a normal $N(0,1)$ distribution).

I have the simulated values, but I want to check the trajectory of future values, while only the simulated values and the functional form of the nonlinear model are available.

How to predict the trajectory of these values when the parameters $r$ and $N_0$ are unknown?

Comment: +1 After editing this question I realized I might have misunderstood your model.  The issue is whether the trajectory evolves *without* errors and its values are merely measured with error (so it's not a stochastic process--it's a function sampled at discrete times), or whether its evolution does include the errors $\varepsilon_t$ (making it a stochastic process).  If it is the former, then please modify the formulas to reflect that.

Comment: So you have a model $x_{t+1} = r  x_t  \exp (-x_t)$, and you want to estimate $x_0$ and $r$ from data $y_t = x_t + \varepsilon_t$, which has standard normal measurement errors?

Comment: I have the simulated values, but I want to check the trajectory of future values, while only the simulated values and the functional form of the nonlinear model are available.

Comment: This model has several qualitatively different regimes, depending on whether $r\lt 0$, $r=0$, $0\lt r\le 1$, $r \gt 1$, and the sign of $N_0$. To keep answers from becoming unnecessarily broad or irrelevant, could you indicate which conditions are likely to hold in your case?

Comment: Double checking, the errors in $N^*_t+1$ are inside the $exp(.)$.It's a dynamical growth populational model, so $r$ and $N_0$ are supposed to be greater than $0$. My simulated values for $N^*_t+1$ are: 8.76166428 0.01241660 0.17645902 2.43564678 3.13179516 1.55528002 8.39002277 0.02180966 0.70251147 4.04687339.